# What more can I do to improve performance of my SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

I am writing this because I have followed advice I have picked up on a variety of forums, blogs, and documentation sites but am still experiencing what I feel like is unnecessary latency in a query. I guess I am looking for either

1. validation that I have done what I can
2. suggestions on what more I can do.

I have two tables, `SiteCategories` and a `Sessions` table

```
CREATE TABLE [assets].[SiteCategories]
(
    [SiteCategoryId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SiteCategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SiteCategoryDesc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('system'),
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('system'),

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SiteCategoryId] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
)

CREATE TABLE [session].[Sessions]
(
    [SessionId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SessionUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AssetNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SessionUTCOffset] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionStartUTCTimestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [SessionStartTimestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [SessionEndTimestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [SessionLanguage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SessionLength] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionCity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionState] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SessionPostalCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionCountry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionSiteCategoryId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionSiteName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionLocationName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionLocationOwner] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionRegion] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionStartMethod] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionStartMethodId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionEndMethod] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SessionEndMethodId] [bigint] NULL,
    [SessionTotalValue] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [SessionTotalDiscount] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [SessionTotalPayment] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [OperatingSystem] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OnlineAccessCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CaptureSource] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('system'),
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('system'),

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SessionId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [session].[Sessions] WITH NOCHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Sessions_ToSiteCategories] 
       FOREIGN KEY([SessionSiteCategoryId])
       REFERENCES [assets].[SiteCategories] ([SiteCategoryId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [session].[Sessions] 
    CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Sessions_ToSiteCategories]
GO
```

The `SiteCategories` table only has about 14 records.

The `Sessions` table contains 1,291,482 records.

I have written a very minimal query which joins the two, extracting records for a date range ...

```
DECLARE @nUndefined INT = -1;
DECLARE @catID BIGINT   = -1;

SELECT 
    [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp,
    [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId,
    [hdr].AssetNumber
FROM 
    session.Sessions AS [hdr]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    assets.SiteCategories AS [cat] ON [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = [cat].SiteCategoryId
WHERE 
    [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'FE%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'QA%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%alex%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%desk%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%test%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%R&D%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber <> 'base'
    AND (@catID = @nUndefined OR (@catID <> @nUndefined AND [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = @catID))
    AND [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'
```

The query returns 1,172,082 records in about 13 seconds (according to SSMS). I need to return these records as the basis for further data aggregation. Starting with 13 seconds is a tedious amount of time to have to wait and it seems like it could/should be quicker. I know 1 million records is nothing to sneeze at but it's not exactly "big data" (is it?). Of course, the smaller the date range and result set the quicker the query.

The index I have added to the `Sessions` table includes all three of the lookup fields as well as including any returned fields (in this case just the indexed fields) so that any return to the original table is unnecessary as it can query and extract all it needs from the index.

I have also run `UPDATE STATISTICS` against the tables and indexes ...

Are my expectations overly optimistic? Is 13 seconds for this data volume and query within the realm of reason or am I missing something?

Thanks,
G

**EDIT - ADDED EXECUTION PLAN**

[image]

**EDIT- UPDATED QUERY AND EXECUTION PLAN**

In an effort to incorporate all the suggestions (thanks a TON by the way!), I have trimmed down the query to the bare necessities.

```
DECLARE @nUndefined INT = -1;
DECLARE @catID BIGINT   = @nUndefined;

SELECT 
    [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp, 
    [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId,
    [hdr].AssetNumber
FROM 
    session.Sessions AS [hdr]
WHERE 
    (@catID = @nUndefined OR 
         (@catID <> @nUndefined AND [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = @catID))
    AND [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'
```

[image]

**EDIT - INDEX**

This is the index that the query is using. I have indexed ALL the fields that are being filtered on and even included those fields in the index to prevent needing to go from the index to the table to fetch the actual data.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SessionStartTimestamp] ON [session].[Sessions]
(
    [SessionStartTimestamp] DESC,
    [SessionSiteCategoryId] ASC,
    [AssetNumber] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: This query will most likely always need to perform a full table scan because all of the `NOT LIKE '%something%'`, this makes it so you can't use an index on that column

Comment: Post execution plan... the `like` conditions aren't going to help your performance.  It may pay to query without all the `likes` into a temp table and then restrict by `AssetNumber` afterwards.

Comment: Can you also include the actual (not expected) execution plan from Sql Server? This can vary depending on the nature of the data and the query used so a community member generated plan from your schema with no data could be different than a plan generated from your data.

Comment: I have always been taught that LIKE comparisons (and cursors) tend to be hogs and avoid them when possible. However, I have actually run this query without any of the AssetNumber comparisons and it actually takes the same amount of time to run. That's why I have left them in.

Comment: That execution plan does not look right for the query you have in your post. There should be joins and probably some table or index scans. Are you sure this is the plan for the correct query? If you have multiple queries that executed in that same run then the plans will be stacked on top of each other. Or maybe you had just the top of your query highlighted and then executed the sql in which case only the highlighted text will execute.

Comment: I just ran the query and screenshot the Execution plan. With the exception of the actual data what I have above is exactly what I am working with. I think someone suggested below that since no fields from the SiteCatagories table is being returned that the join is probably just being ignored which lines up with the Execution Plan (I think ... not very good at reading these)

Comment: That would make sense. So why even have the join then (what is it you want to retrieve or filter from `assets.SiteCategories`)? It seems that all records (not columns) from `session.Sessions` is what you are retrieving every time.

Comment: If you run this query frequently it might be worth creating a persisted computed column based on the `AssetNumber` tests. An index on that ought to help. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom do you have any indexes except PRIMARY KEYs?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Yes (I thought that the index was included with the CREATE TABLE script - I May have missed it when I cut and pasted). There is an index on the SessionStartTimeStamp, SessionSiteCategoryId and AssetNumber on the Sessions table.

Comment: @igor updated OP with trimmed query and associated actual execution plan.

Comment: So that latest Execution plan and query show the index seek taking 80% of the time. You cant tune the plan any better than that as an index seek is pretty much as good as it gets. You could still look at your index though and structure it so that its optimal, that depends largely on the data. Ideally you want the most deterministic values first. Post your nonclustered index and also the current execution time you are experiencing.

Comment: I do not think it would make much of a difference in speed BUT columns you want in the index strictly for being returned so an additional clustered key lookup is not executed should be done using `INCLUDE`.  `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SessionStartTimestamp] ON [session].[Sessions]
(
    [SessionStartTimestamp] DESC,
    [SessionSiteCategoryId] ASC
) INCLUDE([AssetNumber])`

Comment: Finally your test query has `@catID` as having a `null` value. The execution plan or speed of query could change if this had a value and you might even want 2 indexes where they are almost identical with exception to the listing of which column is indexed on first. Best way to figure out if that would help is to run a couple of tests and see what index the execution plan prefers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your SessionStartTimestamp is indexed, perhaps rather than hashing through the table, take the **smaller bite first**, and then apply the final filters.

```
Select *
From (
    SELECT 
      [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp
    , [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId
    , [hdr].AssetNumber
    FROM session.Sessions AS [hdr]
    WHERE 
      [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'

) [hdr]
LEFT OUTER JOIN assets.SiteCategories AS [cat] ON  [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = [cat].SiteCategoryId
WHERE 
    [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'FE%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'QA%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%alex%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%desk%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%R&D%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber <> 'base'
AND (@catID = @nUndefined OR (@catID <> @nUndefined AND [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = @catID))
```

A wise man once told me "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, It still produced a 13 second response. No worse, but not any faster either.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom  Swing and a miss.  Sorry to waste your time.   Tuning is as much art as it is science.  I just can't imagine why it takes so long.  1.7MM rows is not huge.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom Just curious, have you considered NOLOCK, some hate it, others swear by it.

Answer (score 0):

This KILLS you
That is full table scan

```
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%alex%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%desk%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%R&D%'
```

The solution is to parse that out into a
AssetNumberComponents
So you can search on

```
And AssetNumberComponents.Value NOT IN ('alex', 'desk' .....
```

Index seek versus table scan - uh, big difference

Comment: I had been kicking this around, but the variations in AssetNumber are not finite, where the patterns/components are a little more predictable. This was originally one of the first things I looked at but after having tested with these conditions and without; it doesn't seem to contribute to performance one way or another, so I have just left them as is. For what it's worth ... I was pretty surprised by that.

Comment: I do this on 1 millions documents and 300 millions words broken out and get sub second response time.  The variations do not need to be finite.  You just need a rule  (like a space) to break out the components.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom - is that list of text (alex, desk, test, etc) that you want to exclude relatively static? If so why not create a computed column (*I think that could work with a LIKE but not 100% sure*) or add a bit column that you could updated based on an update/insert trigger (any time Component value changes)? Then filter on that column instead.

Comment: @Igor And I am 100% sure a computed column will not work.  The values need to be broken out into rows.

Comment: @Paparazzi - too bad. The second idea (having a regular column of type bit named ContainsBadAsset or something similar) could work though assuming the list of values that the OP wants to exclude are always the same/static, even better if the text does not change (or does not change frequently). Then the cost is incurred when the record is created or updated. If there are frequent `AssetNumber` value updates though either approach might not be efficient.

Comment: @Igor ... It may be possible to look into the "bit" possibility. Ideally these records should not even be in this table. More recently, I have been started excluding them altogether during the ETL process so this is hopefully a fading issue ...

Comment: @Paparazzi - It probably strays somewhat from the OP but I would love to learn more about your techniques for sub-second responses on such large data sets.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom - then it sounds like the best answer is to remove these records completely from the table and update the ETL process to ensure they are also excluded from new imports. That would solve this (*major*) part of the problem.

Comment: @igor Go away. Post an answer.

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom But it is in my answer.   You populate the table via parsing and get an index seek on AssetNumber.Component NOT IN ('alex', 'desk' .....  Like 10,000 time better than a column scan.

Answer (score -1):

So since all your WHERE clause is on `[hdr]` table, it does not make sense to do a LEFT JOIN followed by WHERE.

```
WHERE 
    [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'FE%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'QA%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%alex%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%desk%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%R&D%'
AND [hdr].AssetNumber <> 'base'
AND (@catID = @nUndefined OR (@catID <> @nUndefined AND [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = @catID))
AND [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'
```

Instead you should restrict your [hdr] table followed by a JOIN like below

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
 SessionStartTimestamp datetime,
, SessionSiteCategoryId int
, AssetNumber nvarchar(500)
)
-- please correct the data types as per your need in #temp table

GO

 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_tempindex ON #temp(SessionSiteCategoryId)    

GO

SELECT 
      [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp
    , [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId
    , [hdr].AssetNumber
    INTO #temp FROM session.Sessions AS [hdr]
    WHERE 
        [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'FE%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE 'QA%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%alex%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%desk%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%test%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber NOT LIKE '%R&D%'
    AND [hdr].AssetNumber <> 'base'
    AND [hdr].SessionStartTimestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-28 23:59:59'


SELECT 
 hdr.* 
FROM
#tmp hdr
LEFT OUTER JOIN assets.SiteCategories AS [cat] 
ON [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = [cat].SiteCategoryId 
WHERE (@catID = @nUndefined OR (@catID <> @nUndefined AND [hdr].SessionSiteCategoryId = @catID))
```

And if you have a nonclustered index on AssetNumber column, this will boost up.

P.S.: Consider adding column store index on the `session.Sessions` table, if you have SQL server 2012 and above

Comment: The optimizer will probably see those queries as equivalent

Comment: Wrong - [hdr] is the left side

Comment: @Paparazzi still is

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is not with joining 14 records table.

Comment: @IvanStarostin you are correct. That is why I suggested that OP should use a non clustered index on the AssetNumber column. And used all WHERE in the temp table on that column alone.